# Same XSL in two different transforms gives different results

Tags: xml, xslt

For this XML:

```
<TopLevel>
    <NextLevel Label="(123,456,789)"/>
</TopLevel>
```

I use the following block of XSL to parse those three segments into three variables (and keep the whole label for other purposes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="//TopLevel">
<xsl:variable name="LabelAll" select="NextLevel/@Label"/>
<xsl:variable name="Label1" select="substring-before(substring-after($LabelAll,'('),',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="Label2" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($LabelAll,'('),','),',')"/>
<xsl:variable name="Label3" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($LabelAll, ','),','),')')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$Label1"/><!-- <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> -->
<xsl:value-of select="$Label2"/><!-- <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> -->
<xsl:value-of select="$Label3"/><!-- <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works perfectly in two different XSL transforms. Then I tried to put it into three additional XSL transforms, but in those other transforms, it always assigns `789` to `LabelAll`; `Label1`, `Label2` and `Label3` are empty.

For troubleshooting, I modified the XML to this:

```
<TopLevel>
    <NextLevel Label="(123,456,789,ABC,XYZ,PDQ)"/>
</TopLevel>
```

Now, `LabelAll` becomes `789,ABC,XYZ,PDQ)`, almost like the substring calls are interfering with each other somehow.

Another possibility: the transform engine I am using is a service that runs in the background and gets triggered to apply multiple transforms, for multiple outputs, to a single source XML. Is it possible that the engine is mixing up stuff from different transforms?

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced using only your code: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQm

Comment: I only get the issue, as far as I can tell, with the engine running as a service. If I use XMLNotePad to apply the transforms, I don't see the issue. This is why I am suspicious of the engine. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

> Another possibility: the transform engine I am using is a service that runs in the background and gets triggered to apply multiple transforms, for multiple outputs, to a single source XML. Is it possible that the engine is mixing up stuff from different transforms?

Yes, it's possible, if you've invoked it incorrectly and without regard to thread-safety. For example, if you're using JAXP and use the Transformer object in multiple threads concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: there was another transform that was making an intermediate XML with modified value of the attribute in question. The transform I was working on was configured by the service to use the intermediate result XML instead of the original. Thx!